# How to detect shake in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, shake

I want to detect a shake gesture in a UITableViewCell, but no shake is being registered. Is there a way I can detect a shake in a UITableView cell?

This is the code I'm using now:

```
extension MyTableViewCell {
    override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("shake started")
    }
    
    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("shake stopped")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a table view cell? Do you want as many "shake started" being printed as the number of cells you have on the screen?

Comment: There are specific properties in the tableviewcell that being animated in the cell and I wanted to change the animation occurring in the cell when a shake occurs @Sweeper

Comment: So it seems like you want all your cells to respond to the motion event, which isn't really a thing, I don't think. There is only _one_ "first responder". You can at most make one cell respond to motion events. What you can do instead is to have whatever is holding the table view (e.g. your VC) handle the motion event, update a variable, then reload the visible cells.

Comment: As @Sweeper says, detecting the device being shaken under `UITableView` is pointless.

Comment: You need to use the notification.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest adding your motionBegan/motionEnded methods to your view controller, and then updating the model that backs your table view to reflect the shake event and tell the table view to reload. (For example, you might add an `isShaking` property to an array of structs that holds the settings for your table view cells.) In your `cellForRowAt()` method, check the model to see if your `isShaking` property for that `IndexPath` is true, and if it is, make whatever change to your cell animation that you need.